# Facebook : No permission to publish the video

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to upload video using c# facebook graph api, and its working fine for user development account, i am able to post on wall, but when i try to other user i am getting error :

**(OAuthException - #100) (#100) No permission to publish the video**

This is my sample code

```
**var fb = new Facebook.FacebookClient(token);
            dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
            parameters.source = new Facebook.FacebookMediaObject { ContentType = "video/mp4", FileName = "video.mp4" }.SetValue(File.ReadAllBytes(@"D:\home\site\wwwroot\\Videos\abc.mp4"));

            parameters.title = "test title";
            parameters.description = "test description";
            dynamic result = fb.Post("/me/videos", parameters);**
```

where i set the permission

```
**scope=publish_actions**
```

Please help me, Thank you in Advance.

Comment: are you trying with a user who is not admin, developer or tester of the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make `publish_actions` work for other users without a role in the App, you need to go through Login Review. Everything you need to know about that is in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review

If you are indeed trying with an App Admin/Developer/Tester and it still does not work, debug the Access Token in the Debugger and make sure `publish_actions` is authorized correctly: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: Does not answer the question

Comment: why not? back then (2015) it was correct. publish_actions is deprecated now though.